# How can I find out that telegram sends messages to the url that I set as webhook

Tags: webhooks, telegram, telegram-bot, pem, jks

I did these steps to setWebhook for my telegram bot:

I get .cer file from my https url(https://mywebapp.com/index./index.jsp) and then I generate .jks file in this order (I went to jre/bin folder in cmd):

> keytool -importcert -file mywebapp.cer -keystore myKeystore.jks -alias mywebapp.com

Then I convert it to .p12 file :

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myKeystore.jks -destkeystore myPkcs.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12

And then I convert .p12 file to .pem file by openSSL :

> openssl pkcs12 -in myPkcs.p12 -out myPem.pem

Then I generate this form to set webhook:

```
<form id="telegramForm" action="https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setWebhook" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="https://mywebapp.com/index.jsp">
            <input type="file" name='certificate' id='certificate'>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

and I browse myPem.pem file from input[type=file]. I submit this form and I get this response:

> {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}

But when I (or a user telegram) send some messages (like  text message "hello") to my robot by telegram application, https://mywebapp.com/index.jsp (url that was set as webhook) does not get any request.

How can I find out that telegram sends messages (that users send to my telegram bot) to the url that I set as webhook? How can I find out this url (https://mywebapp.com/index.jsp) can receive messages that are sent to my telegram bot by telegram users?
Why I can't get messages that telegram users send to my bot? how can I get them?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to set your web hook something like this: `https://mywebapp.com/index.php`

`index.php` is your bot processor file.

place this code for test in your `index.php` file:

```
<?php

define('BOT_TOKEN','1234:xyz'); //replace second parameter with your bot token
$command_prefix_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . BOT_TOKEN;
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$rep = json_decode(file_get_contents($command_prefix_url . '/SendMessage?chat_id=' .
    $update->message->chat->id . '&text='.urlencode($update->message->text)));
?>
```

now each time, if anyone send you some text, it will receive that text from bot.

If you want to know , is there any one sent something to your bot, you can save this `$update` to database or resend it to your(admin) client!!(lot of messages)

Comment: I set https://mywebapp.com/index.jsp as webhook. I write that if https://mywebapp.com/index.jsp gets a request, write request's parameter in a log file (https://mywebapp.com/log.txt).But when I send message to robot, nothing be written in log file. why? Are my steps to set webhook wrong?thanks.@Tick Tock

Comment: @AtefehRashidi How did you this job? what was your steps? Does my code work?(Does you receive something when you send a text to your bot via telegram client(app) )?

Comment: I can not test your code because my server side code is by jsp and java. Are my steps for generating self-signed certificate (as telegram document said) and setting webhook true? It is not important that it is by php or jsp. I just want to know why my webhook does not get any request from telegram bot? thanks.@Tick Tock

Comment: @AtefehRashidi you can write a code by java or any programming language, I wrote that simple code for testing and for know what is the problem, If you don't know anything about php, I tell you what is it doing ,then you can write it in java. My code gets a message from Telegram, then replies it to sender. If it work then you can go more forward but if it doesn't work then you have real problems with initiating before.